# way to reduce the cost in db2 for count(*)

Tags: db2, query-optimization

Hi I had a DB2 Query as below

```
select count(*) as count from 
table_a,
table_b,
table c

where
b.xxx=234 AND
b.yyy=c.wedf
```

Result SEt:

### Count

618543562

For the above query i even tried with Count(1) but when i took the access plan, cost is same.

```
select count(1) as count from 
    table_a,
    table_b,
    table c

    where
    b.xxx=234 AND
    b.yyy=c.wedf
```

Result SEt:

### Count

618543562

Is there any other way to reduce the cost.

PS: **b.xxx,b.yyy, c.wedf is indexed**..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the problem are statistics on the table. Did you execute **Runstats**? Probably, the data distribution or the quantity of rows that has to be read is a lot, and DB2 concludes that is better to read the whole table, instead of process an index, and then fetch the rows from the table.

It seems that both queries are taking the same **access plan**, and I think they are doing **table scans**.

Are the three columns part of the same index? or they are indexed separately? If they are part of different indexes, is there any **ANDing** between indexes in the access plan? If there is not ANDing with different indexes, the columns has to be read from the table in order to process the predicates.

The reason count(1) and count(*) are giving the same cost, is because both has to do a TableScan.

Please, take a look at the access plan, not only the results in timerons, but also the steps. Is the access plan taking the indexes? how many sorts is executing?

Try to change the **optimization level**, and you will see that the access plans change. I think you are executing with the default one (5)

If you want to force the query to take in account an index, you can create an [**optimization profile**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0060612.html)

Comment: Does the index has the three columns?

Answer (score 1):

What is the relation between (B,C) tables and A table. In your query you just use [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) between A and (B,C). So it is the MAIN performance issue.

If you really need this count just multiply counts for A and (B,C):

```
select
     (select count(*) from a) 
      * 
     (select count(*) from b, c where b.xxx=234 AND b.yyy=c.wedf )
```

for DB2 use this:

```
     select a1.cnt*
            (select count(*) as cnt2 from b, c where b.xxx=234 AND b.yyy=c.wedf )
     from 
        (select count(*) as cnt1  from a) a1
```

Comment: Hi can you give a correct syntax to execute the above query..since am getting error is interval qualifier expected

Comment: Please, even in example queries, always explicitly define your joins, don't use the implicit-join syntax.